# Performance of Java matrix math libraries?

Tags: java, math, matrix, performance

We are computing something whose runtime is bound by matrix operations.  (Some details below if interested.) This experience prompted the following question:

Do folk have experience with the performance of Java libraries for matrix math (e.g., multiply, inverse, etc.)?  For example:

- [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/)
- [COLT](http://acs.lbl.gov/~hoschek/colt/)
- [Apache commons math](http://commons.apache.org/math/)

I searched and found nothing.

---

Details of our speed comparison:

We are using Intel FORTRAN (ifort (IFORT) 10.1 20070913).  We have reimplemented it in Java (1.6) using Apache commons math 1.2 matrix ops, and it agrees to all of its digits of accuracy.  (We have reasons for wanting it in Java.)  (Java doubles, Fortran real*8).  Fortran: 6 minutes, Java 33 minutes, same machine.  jvisualm profiling shows much time spent in RealMatrixImpl.{getEntry,isValidCoordinate} (which appear to be gone in unreleased Apache commons math 2.0, but 2.0 is no faster).  Fortran is using Atlas BLAS routines (dpotrf, etc.).

Obviously this could depend on our code in each language, but we believe most of the time is in equivalent matrix operations.

In several other computations that do not involve libraries, Java has not been much slower, and sometimes much faster.

Comment: The tricky matrix math ops are at least O(n^3)... worse come to worse, I suppose you could time and test...

Comment: Why do you need inverses? For almost all applications, you don't need the actual inverse. Computing the inverse is a bad idea because of stability issues.

Comment: @Calyth: Yes, we could time.  I was wondering if others already had.
@Ying Xiao: Yes, inverses are to be avoided.  However, this computation seems most straightforward using it.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_correlation#Using_matrix_inversion.

Comment: @Calyth That is wrong, there are more efficient methods than O(n^3) using a divide and conquer approach.

Comment: Yes, O(n^log2(7)) is at least possible. It is shown by Strassen and is quite simple to implement. There are better asymptotic times though but they can have unpractical big constants.

Comment: Fastest native performance is from JCublas. If you need fast linear algebra, you need GPUs. JOCL with clMath might also work and be portable to CPUs (and even multi-platform w/o recompiling), but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Just to add my 2 cents. I've compared some of these libraries. I attempted to matrix multiply a 3000 by 3000 matrix of doubles with itself. The results are as follows.

Using multithreaded ATLAS with C/C++, Octave, Python and R, the time taken was around 4 seconds.

Using Jama with Java, the time taken was 50 seconds.

Using Colt and Parallel Colt with Java, the time taken was 150 seconds!

Using JBLAS with Java, the time taken was again around 4 seconds as JBLAS uses multithreaded ATLAS.

So for me it was clear that the Java libraries didn't perform too well. However if someone has to code in Java, then the best option is JBLAS. Jama, Colt and Parallel Colt are not fast.

Comment: I guess you were using a multicore machine, so these results are strongly affected by whether the library uses multicore or not?  For some purposes, eg when one is parallelizing using mpi or hadoop etc, the important time is actually the *singlecore* time, since the mpi/hadoop implementation takes care of parallelizing things. (At least, for me jblas was about 2.5 faster than jama, not 10 times faster than jama as you got. )

Comment: I've just released v1.0 of [netlib-java](https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java)... the performance is on-par (and sometimes surpasses) Fortran code, and it can use machine optimised natives without any changes to user code. Please consider this when looking for low-level linear algebra libraries. I also maintain [MTJ](https://github.com/fommil/matrix-toolkits-java), which makes use of netlib-java. In Scala, use [Breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze) (also powered by `netlib-java`)

Comment: Using ND4j and java - my relatively old laptop completes the suggested multiplication within 219 millis. While python + numpy completes it within 349 millis

Comment: And just to add on my last comment about using nd4j, I used native-platform as its backend, if I use cuda-platform it takes about 1 millisecond

Comment: Did you publish your code for benchmarks somewhere?

Answer (score 114):

I'm the author of Java Matrix Benchmark ([JMatBench](http://lessthanoptimal.github.io/Java-Matrix-Benchmark/)) and I'll give my thoughts on this discussion.

There are significant difference between Java libraries and while there is no clear winner across the whole range of operations, there are a few clear leaders as can be seen in the [latest performance results](http://lessthanoptimal.github.io/Java-Matrix-Benchmark/runtime/2013_10_Corei7v2600/) (October 2013).

If you are working with "large" matrices and can use native libraries, then the clear winner (about 3.5x faster) is [MTJ](https://github.com/fommil/matrix-toolkits-java/) with [system optimised netlib](https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java/). If you need a pure Java solution then [MTJ](https://github.com/fommil/matrix-toolkits-java/), [OjAlgo](http://ojalgo.org/), [EJML](http://ejml.org/) and [Parallel Colt](https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/parallelcolt) are good choices.  For small matrices EJML is the clear winner.

The libraries I did not mention showed significant performance issues or were missing key features.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention that your benchmark is really handy! Thanks for putting your time into it.

Comment: JBLAS appears to support SVD as of Sep '13: http://mikiobraun.github.io/jblas/javadoc/org/jblas/Singular.html#fullSVD(org.jblas.DoubleMatrix)

Comment: wonderful work, thx a lot.

Comment: Is there a list somewhere of the libraries you evaluated but did not publish results for, and the reasons for each?

Comment: MTJ seems abandoned: the repository is archived and the last commit was in 2016.

Answer (score 53):

I'm the main author of jblas and wanted to point out that I've released Version 1.0 in late December 2009. I worked a lot on the packaging, meaning that you can now just download a "fat jar" with ATLAS and JNI libraries for Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, 32 and 64 bit (except for Windows). This way you will get the native performance just by adding the jar file to your classpath. Check it out at http://jblas.org!

Comment: inspired by your work, I did a similar thing in [netlib-java](https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java/) ;-)

Comment: Haha, me too, for [jeigen](https://github.com/hughperkins/jeigen) :-)

Comment: JogAmp does the same, see jogamp-fat.jar. Good idea :)

Comment: I'm getting a link error when I try to use the JAR in my project.  Is there a configuration I've missed to use the fat JAR?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72593905/how-to-run-jblas-java-linear-algebra-without-native-libraries

Answer (score 9):

I just compared Apache Commons Math with jlapack.

Test: singular value decomposition of a random 1024x1024 matrix.

Machine: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E6750  @ 2.66GHz, linux x64

Octave code: A=rand(1024); tic;[U,S,V]=svd(A);toc

```
results                                execution time
---------------------------------------------------------
Octave                                 36.34 sec

JDK 1.7u2 64bit
    jlapack dgesvd                     37.78 sec
    apache commons math SVD            42.24 sec


JDK 1.6u30 64bit
    jlapack dgesvd                     48.68 sec
    apache commons math SVD            50.59 sec

Native routines
Lapack* invoked from C:                37.64 sec
Intel MKL                               6.89 sec(!)
```

My conclusion is that jlapack called from JDK 1.7 is very close to the native
binary performance of lapack. I used the lapack binary library coming with linux distro and invoked the dgesvd routine to get the U,S and VT matrices as well. All tests were done using double precision on exactly the same matrix each run (except Octave).

Disclaimer - I'm not an expert in linear algebra, not affiliated to any of the libraries above and this is not a rigorous benchmark.
It's a 'home-made' test, as I was interested comparing the performance increase of JDK 1.7 to 1.6 as well as commons math SVD to jlapack.

Answer (score 8):

I can't really comment on specific libraries, but in principle there's little reason for such operations to be slower in Java. Hotspot generally does the kinds of things you'd expect a compiler to do: it compiles basic math operations on Java variables to corresponding machine instructions (it uses SSE instructions, but only one per operation); accesses to elements of an array are compiled to use "raw" MOV instructions as you'd expect; it makes decisions on how to allocate variables to registers when it can; it re-orders instructions to take advantage of processor architecture... A possible exception is that as I mentioned, Hotspot will only perform one operation per SSE instruction; in principle you could have a fantastically optimised matrix library that performed multiple operations per instruction, although I don't know if, say, your particular FORTRAN library does so or if such a library even exists. If it does, there's currently no way for Java (or at least, Hotspot) to compete with that (though you could of course write your own native library with those optimisations to call from Java).

So what does all this mean? Well:

- in principle, it is worth hunting around for a better-performing library, though unfortunately I can't recomend one
- if performance is really critical to you, I would consider just coding your own matrix operations, because you may then be able perform certain optimisations that a library generally can't, or that a particular library your using doesn't (if you have a multiprocessor machine, find out if the library is actually multithreaded)

A hindrance to matrix operations is often data locality issues that arise when you need to traverse both row by row and column by column, e.g. in matrix multiplication, since you have to store the data in an order that optimises one or the other. But if you hand-write the code, you can sometimes **combine operations to optimise data locality** (e.g. if you're multiplying a matrix by its transformation, you can turn a column traversal into a row traversal if you write a dedicated function instead of combining two library functions). As usual in life, a library will give you non-optimal performance in exchange for faster development; you need to decide just how important performance is to you.

Answer (score 8):

Jeigen https://github.com/hughperkins/jeigen

- wraps Eigen C++ library http://eigen.tuxfamily.org , which is one of the fastest free C++ libraries available
- relatively terse syntax, eg 'mmul', 'sub'
- handles both dense and sparse matrices

A quick test, by multiplying two dense matrices, ie:

import static jeigen.MatrixUtil.*;

```
int K = 100;
int N = 100000;
DenseMatrix A = rand(N, K);
DenseMatrix B = rand(K, N);
Timer timer = new Timer();
DenseMatrix C = B.mmul(A);
timer.printTimeCheckMilliseconds();
```

Results:

```
Jama: 4090 ms
Jblas: 1594 ms
Ojalgo: 2381 ms (using two threads)
Jeigen: 2514 ms
```

- Compared to jama, everything is faster :-P
- Compared to jblas, Jeigen is not quite as fast, but it handles sparse matrices.
- Compared to ojalgo, Jeigen takes about the same amount of elapsed time, but only using one core, so Jeigen uses half the total cpu.  Jeigen has a terser syntax, ie 'mmul' versus 'multiplyRight'

Comment: Jeigen looks awesome! I recently implemented Eigen in Java using JNI and a DLL for solve very large sparse matrices. My version with the DLL is over 20 faster than parallel colt for my tests (over 8000x8000 matrices). I wish I had know about Jeigen!

Comment: Hi, I tried to multiply two matrices (dim 500x5000 and 5000x500) and check times. With Jeigen I got around 200ms, same as EJML. Then I tried in C++ Eigen, but wrapped in R (with Rcpp and RcppEigen), and I got 70ms. Do you think that there is margin for further speed up? Or is the R/C++ version calling a different matmul routine? Or did I miss some optimization? I am using Eclipse in Windows.

Comment: @Halberdier The Java Native Interface is intentionally made slow, or at any rate, it is slow. It's totally possible that the R interface to C is much faster. The Python interface to C is much faster AFAIK, and I think that R and Python have much in common. (The larger the matrices the less the JNI overhead.)

Comment: @HughPerkins Your explanation makes definitely sense, but I don't think it's enough to explain such a big difference, which by the way does not decrease when the matrix size gets higher. Also I noted that in my multicore laptop the Eigen in R test raises the CPU up to 100%, none of the other tests does that. My theory is that the DLLs in Jeigen jars have been compiled without enabling OpenMP. I don't know if adding it has portability issues and if not how it can be done.

Comment: Ah, right, so yeah, Jeigen is single-threaded. I don't remember why I made it single-threaded. Feel free to dabble, and open a PR to provide a multi-threaded option.

Answer (score 6):

There's a benchmark of various matrix packages available in java up on
http://code.google.com/p/java-matrix-benchmark/ for a few different hardware configurations. But it's no substitute for doing your own benchmark.

Performance is going to vary with the type of hardware you've got (cpu, cores, memory, L1-3 cache, bus speed), the size of the matrices and the algorithms you intend to use.  Different libraries have different takes on concurrency for different algorithms, so there's no single answer.  You may also find that the overhead of translating to the form expected by a native library negates the performance advantage for your use case (some of the java libraries have more flexible options regarding matrix storage, which can be used for further performance optimizations).

Generally though, JAMA, Jampack and COLT are getting old, and do not represent the state of the current performance available in Java for linear algebra.  More modern libraries make more effective use of multiple cores and cpu caches.  JAMA was a reference implementation, and pretty much implements textbook algorithms with little regard to performance.  COLT and IBM Ninja were the first java libraries to show that performance was possible in java, even if they lagged 50% behind native libraries.

Answer (score 5):

I'm the author of [la4j](http://la4j.org) (Linear Algebra for Java) library and here is my point. I've been working on la4j for 3 years (the latest release is 0.4.0 [01 Jun 2013]) and only now I can start doing performace analysis and optimizations since I've just covered the minimal required functional. So, la4j isn't as fast as I wanted but I'm spending loads of my time to change it.

I'm currently in the middle of porting new version of la4j to [JMatBench](http://code.google.com/p/java-matrix-benchmark/) platform. I hope new version will show better performance then previous one since there are several improvement I made in la4j such as much faster internal matrix format, unsafe accessors and fast blocking algorithm for matrix multiplications.

Comment: No - la4j is really uncompetitive. See http://code.google.com/p/java-matrix-benchmark/

Comment: It has changed a lot. I've released two versions of the library since your answer. Current release is 0.4.0. And it just flies.

Answer (score 4):

Have you taken a look at the [Intel Math Kernel Library](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl?wapkw=intel%20math%20kernel%20library&wapkwg=featured)? It claims to outperform even [ATLAS](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/). MKL can be [used in Java](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/performance-tools-for-software-developers-how-do-i-use-intel-mkl-with-java) through JNI wrappers.

Comment: We have that. a) Its licensing is more restrictive than Atlas (so we can't use all our computers); b) it's not Java (and as I said we have reasons to want to be in Java).

Comment: i.e., this is not an answer to my question about Java libraries (but I don't have the reputation to downvote it).

Comment: @dfrankow: I've updated my answer to address your concern on using it in Java.

Comment: +1, If it's speed you're looking for, this seems to be the way to go

Comment: The last link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

Linalg code that relies heavily on Pentiums and later processors' vector computing capabilities (starting with the MMX extensions, like LAPACK and now Atlas BLAS) is not "fantastically optimized", but simply industry-standard. To replicate that perfomance in Java you are going to need native libraries. I have had the same performance problem as you describe (mainly, to be able to compute Choleski decompositions) and have found nothing really efficient: Jama is pure Java, since it is supposed to be just a template and reference kit for implementers to follow... which never happened. You know Apache math commons... As for COLT, I have still to test it but it seems to rely heavily on Ninja improvements, most of which were reached by building an ad-hoc Java compiler, so I doubt it's going to help.
At that point, I think we "just" need a collective effort to build a native Jama implementation...

Comment: Good point!  An alpha-stage project with JNI wrappers for Atlas: http://www.jblas.org.  Author's blog post: http://mikiobraun.blogspot.com/2008/10/matrices-jni-directbuffers-and-number.html

Answer (score 3):

Building on Varkhan's post that Pentium-specific native code would do better:

- jBLAS: An alpha-stage project with JNI wrappers for Atlas: http://www.jblas.org.

  - Author's blog post: http://mikiobraun.blogspot.com/2008/10/matrices-jni-directbuffers-and-number.html.
- MTJ: Another such project: http://code.google.com/p/matrix-toolkits-java/

Answer (score 3):

We have used COLT for some pretty large serious financial calculations and have been very happy with it. In our heavily profiled code we have almost never had to replace a COLT implementation with one of our own.

In their own testing (obviously not independent) I think they claim within a factor of 2 of the Intel hand-optimised assembler routines. The trick to using it well is making sure that you understand their design philosophy, and avoid extraneous object allocation.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that if you are creating a lot of high dimensional Matrices, you can make Jama about 20% faster if you change it to use a single dimensional array instead of a two dimensional array.  This is because Java doesn't support multi-dimensional arrays as efficiently. ie. it creates an array of arrays.

Colt does this already, but I have found it is more complicated and more powerful than Jama which may explain why simple functions are slower with Colt.

The answer really depends on that you are doing.  Jama doesn't support a fraction of the things Colt can do which make make more of a difference.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out the [jblas](http://jblas.org/) project. It's a relatively new Java library that uses BLAS, LAPACK and ATLAS for high-performance matrix operations.

The developer has posted some [benchmarks](http://blog.mikiobraun.de/2009/04/some-benchmark-numbers-for-jblas.html) in which jblas comes off favourably against MTJ and Colt.

Answer (score 2):

For 3d graphics applications the lwjgl.util vector implementation out-performed above mentioned jblas by a factor of about 3.

I have done 1 million matrix multiplications of a vec4 with a 4x4 matrix.

lwjgl finished in about 18ms, jblas required about 60ms.

(I assume, that the JNI approach is not very suitable for fast successive application of relatively small multiplications. Since the translation/mapping may take more time than the actual execution of the multiplication.)

Answer (score 1):

There's also [UJMP](http://www.ujmp.org/)

Answer (score 0):

There are many different freely available java linear algebra libraries. http://www.ujmp.org/java-matrix/benchmark/
Unfortunately that benchmark only gives you info about matrix multiplication (with transposing the test does not allow the different libraries to exploit their respective design features).

What you should look at is how these linear algebra libraries perform when asked to compute various matrix decompositions.
http://ojalgo.org/matrix_compare.html

Answer (score 0):

Matrix Tookits Java (MTJ) was already mentioned before, but perhaps it's worth mentioning again for anyone else stumbling onto this thread. For those interested, it seems like there's also talk about having MTJ replace the linalg library in the [apache commons math 2.0](http://www.nabble.com/commons-math%2C-matrix-toolkits-java-and-consolidation-to23537813.html#a23574199), though I'm not sure how that's progressing lately.

Answer (score 0):

You should add Apache Mahout to your shopping list.