# How can I use Scheme/Lisp/Clojure for Matrix/LP problems?

Tags: java, lisp, clojure, matrix, scheme

I need to perform numerical analysis like that supported by MatLab or NumPy.
Is there a good library that is supported by Scheme/Lisp/Clojure(Java)? I don't want to leave my round braces.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

For Common Lisp, see

- [Matlisp](http://matlisp.sourceforge.net): a matrix package for Common Lisp (includes BLAS and LAPACK);
- [GSLL](http://common-lisp.net/project/gsll/): GNU Scientific Library for Lisp;

and [others on cliki](http://www.cliki.net/Mathematics).

Answer (score 6):

**Incanter** is a Clojure-based, R-like statistical computing and graphics environment for the JVM. At the core of Incanter are the Parallel Colt numerics library, a multithreaded version of Colt, and the JFreeChart charting library, as well as several other Java and Clojure libraries.

http://incanter.org/

Comment: WOW this looks interesting. Are there any benchmarks available?

Comment: +1 for Incanter -  been using it for a few weeks with absolutely no issues. Haven't really pushed performance but it seems good.

Comment: Incanter is using Parallel Colt, which in several benchmarks has shown to be ~10x slower than LAPACK. If anyone has *first-hand experience* with a matrix library for a Lisp using LAPACK/BLAS that has been tested heavily (MATLAB/NumPy/R), please let me know. I have been looking and haven't found it.

Comment: Clatrix is a Clojure wrapper of BLAS: worth looking at. It's also a `core.matrix` implementation, which is important as it brings a general purpose N-dimensional array API to Clojure.

Answer (score 5):

### Lisp:

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/ai-repository/ai/lang/lisp/code/math/matrix/0.html

### Java:

Jama:http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/
Colt:[http://acs.lbl.gov/~hoschek/colt/](http://acs.lbl.gov/%7Ehoschek/colt/)
Apache commons math: http://commons.apache.org/math/

If speed is important, you can try **Parallel Colt:**
http://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/parallelcolt

Comment: Speed discussion for Java libraries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529457/performance-of-java-matrix-math-libraries

Comment: for the lisp library "Last Web update on Mon Feb 13 10:30:23 1995" xD

Comment: Math doesn't change much.  The Lisp library probably still works fine.

Answer (score 3):

For PLT Scheme see the [plt-linalg](http://planet.plt-scheme.org/display.ss?package=plt-linalg.plt&owner=wmfarr) package on planet.  There is also [mzgsl](http://planet.plt-scheme.org/display.ss?package=mzgsl.plt&owner=wmfarr) which has bindings for the GNU Scientific Library.

Answer (score 3):

`core.matrix` is now under development which will bring comprehensive N-dimensional array features (NumPy style) to Clojure: https://github.com/mikera/matrix-api

An important point about `core.matrix` is that it supports multiple different back-end matrix implementations through the same API.

For example, there is already a pretty good / fast pure Java core.matrix implementation called [vectorz-clj](https://github.com/mikera/vectorz-clj), and another one called [Clatrix](https://github.com/tel/clatrix) that uses the native JBLAS libraries.

Disclaimer: I'm a major contributor to both core.matrix and vectorz-clj.: