# Java Jama matrix

Tags: java, matrix, jama

I am working with [Jama Matrix](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/). I used it for LSI. It works all fine. However, when I pass a big matrix like, 8000x8000 it kills my whole system. I am simply calling SVD then reducing matrix size and adding up. Nothing else !

Any idea? How can I solve this problem?

core2du

Ram = 10GB

Java runtime setting

-Xmx5000M

There is no other program running while I execute Jama matrix code

Comment: By "kills my whole system", what do you mean? If you get an `OutOfMemoryError`, this is entirely likely because an 8000x200 array takes ~12Mb of memory. SVD's constructor creates a whole stack of new arrays. Even with that one call, you might be approaching the 64Mb default maximum memory allocation for the JVM (assuming you're using Oracle/Sun JVM).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have 10GB RAM in my computer. It is using JDK 1.5 and I already allocated 5GB to my program. I am sorry for confusion. Kills my whole system means, it takes days to process this small matrix with Jama. I am not using anything else. I just pass simple matrix to Jama package.

Comment: I would suspect that you solve the problem by using a different library or smaller matrices, because SVD appears to be O(n^3). Failing that, you could try profiling (e.g. with jvisualvm) to see whether you're memory- or CPU-bound, and you could measure with smaller cases and extrapolate to estimate the running time required.

Comment: Did you browse through their [mailing-list archive](http://cio.nist.gov/esd/emaildir/lists/jama/maillist.html)? There are several messages about Jama's SVD implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also use the Jama for SVD and have the same problem in solving big matrix.
In order to reduce memory overflow cases, I have tuned SingularValueDecomposition.java to compact one. The tuning is that in the matrix A it has so many 0 (zero) value so the compact for all of matrices used such as A, U, V, Work, etc only allows memory for available value which is more than 0.
Before you use the compact SVD, you should make A matrix file like
r /t c /t value /n
r /t c /t value /n
... '/t' and '/n' means tab and new line respectively.

examples, (0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0.5), (0, 2, 0), (0, 3, 0.2), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 2, 0), (1, 3, 0.3) and the matrix size is 2*4 (R*C) then you just make file like
MATRIXSIZE /t 2 /t 4 /n
0 /t 1 /t 0.5 /n
0 /t 3 /t 0.2 /n
1 /t 0 /t 1 /n
1 /t 3 /t 0.3 /n

If you would like to use it, please give me your email address (mg.hwang@gmail.com).
I will give more details to use it on email.

I checked the result was right. However, I am not sure how much effective it is for the computer.
Anyway, it works and shows better even if not much.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably facing an out of memory condition. You might want to increase the memory available to your JVM by using the -Xmx option, for instance-Xm256m will give your JVM 256 MB, instead of the default of 64 MB.

You may also consider using alternative libraries that handle memory efficient matrix representations, using the models for sparse matrices like COO, DOK, CSR, etc... Lookup the Wikipedia entry for "sparse matrix" for more details.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529457/performance-of-java-matrix-math-libraries) provides several alternatives to Jama, maybe this'll help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Peter Taylor is absolutely right.

It is an exponential  big o issue. After all calculating the SVD of a 8000 X 8000 matrix is not a piece of cake since you are talking 64,000,000 elements!

If you run the JAMA MagicSquareExample, with a:

32x32 matrix elapse time is 0.062 sec.
64x64 will go up to  0.0328 sec
96x96 will elapse in 1.891 sec
128x128 in 4.5 sec
160x160 in 11.109 sec
 192x192 in 24.063 sec
224x224 in 46.063 sec
256x256 in 83.625 sec
512x512 in 1716.719 sec

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing LSI, then you can make two important optimizations.  First, your matrix is sparse (assuming you're using a term-by-document matrix).  JAMA operates on dense matrices, so you may want to look into finding a different representation.  As Lolo mentioned, this will greatly reduce your overhead.

Second, LSI only requires the top k singular vectors to be computed.  JAMA computes all of the singular values, which is unnecessary in your case.  Moreover, if you only need to the k largest, you can optimize further by using a thin-SVD, which has a significantly lower memory overhead.  Computing the full-SVD for LSI will become almost impossible for large document collections, so you'll eventually have to switch from something other than JAMA if you want to scale.

SVDLIBJ is one possibility for performing a thin-SVD in Java.  The [S-Space Package](http://code.google.com/p/airhead-research/) also has a SVDLIBJ wrapper and command line tool for it, as well as a LSI/LSA implementation if you want to avoid writing LSI altogether.