# Finding inverse of 2d n*n matrix in Java?

Tags: java

I have just printed the matrix of size n*n

Code is (Assume that all matrices are already defined):

```
public class ReadContents { 
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The Matrix Is:");
        double mat[][]=new double[col][col];

        for(k=0;k<col;k++) {
            for(p=0;p<col;p++) {
                mat[k][p]=SubMULTIPL_1[k][p]-ADD[k][p];
                System.out.printf("%2.2f  ",mat[k][p]);
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

But,  I am having the problem of finding the inverse of n*n square matrix
where n=1,2,3..........infinite.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Methods_of_matrix_inversion

Comment: Infinite?  No.  It's not likely without infinite RAM.

Answer (score 2):

- Some Java matrix math
  [libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529457/performance-of-java-matrix-math-libraries) can do the job.
- Not every matrix is [invertible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix)
  perhaps you should test if this
  condition is met.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want the inverse.

I'm betting that you really want to know how to solve a system of equations.  I'd recommend that you look at LU decomposition rather than inverse or Gaussian elimination.  It's more stable.

You'll have a hard time inverting a matrix if the determinant of the matrix is zero or VERY small.