# copying column of a 2D array as 1D array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have a 2D array:

```
int[][] a = new int[4][3];
```

populated such that:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
2 5 7
```

Is there any shortcut method in java to extract lets say column 1 as single array:

```
array1 = {1 4 7 2};
```

Currently what I am doing is traversing through the whole 2D matrix and with if condition (`if j==0`), I traverse over the rows and add values to 1D array.
Just wondering if there is any standard method offered in java for such tasks.

Comment: Why are you traversing the *whole* matrix?  Why not simply: `for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) { b[i] = a[i][0]; }`?

Comment: that is because i need to extract all the columns as separate arrays. and problem is the matrix is so big, so i want to know if there is some simpler method available.

Comment: Then please update your question to explain what you're *really* trying to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no shortcut to doing this.  You have to loop over the arrays, switching the x & y indices.

Comment: Of course, if it's a recurring pattern in your code, you should write a helper method to do it for you.  Or consider whether the fact that you're continually transposing matrices means that your design is broken!

Comment: actually i have to calculate cosineSimilarity which requires traversing over the transposed columns and it is recursive calculation over a huge matrix of the size [2500]x[3000]. The only idea i can think of is to integrated the calculation inside the matrix for now.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such build-in method. You have to write a simple loop.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to [consider use of a matrix library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529457/performance-of-java-matrix-math-libraries).  But this is pretty simple stuff - if this is all you need, you can probably write it quicker than you can get up to speed on a library.