# Ask for matrix lib for java (PCA / linear Regress)

Tags: java, matrix

I am doing a java project. We have to add PCA and linear regress function to this project. Could you tell me java lib that can do these matrix's things? Many Thanks!

BTW, I used to use Matlab Builder For Java to convert the matlab code into the ".jar". However, boss deny this option for the reason of efficency.

Comment: I have trouble believing that Matlab would provide "inefficient" code. You might be able to do better by hooking up to some FORTRAN backend -- but that seems _very_ unlikely. Are you confident "efficiency" was the reason and not licensing or some other less tangible reason? If "efficiency" _is_ the reason, then you're going to have to do some speed tests and determine what speed you _need_ to hit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529457/performance-of-java-matrix-math-libraries this might help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [an excellent site benchmarking different Java matrix libraries](http://code.google.com/p/java-matrix-benchmark/).

> Java Matrix Benchmark (JMatBench) is a tool for evaluating Java linear
>   algebra libraries for speed and stability. This tool can be used by
>   users to select the best library for their application and by
>   developers for identifying bugs and weaknesses. Its goal is to help
>   improve the state of high performance computing on the Java platform.
>
> JMatBench rigorously tests performance across a wide range of matrix
>   sizes and linear algebra operations. The runtime performance benchmark
>   measures how fast each library can run under optimal conditions. It
>   generates accurate results by taking in account JavaVM runtime
>   optimizations, dynamically adjusts to the platform it is run on, and
>   uses well established good benchmarking techniques. The stability
>   benchmark evaluates several standard linear algebra operations for
>   their accuracy, sensitivity, and ability to handle overflow/underflow
>   conditions.

Comment: Thanks! I would like to look the libraries in this website