# Standard Matrix code in java?

Tags: java

I am new to Java, and I need a Matrix class. Is there a standard
library/package for this, or I will have to write it myself?

Thanks

Comment: http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/

Comment: Because you are new writing yourself is beterr!

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan - if the goal is to *use* them, then in this case, "reinventing the wheel" is definitely *NOT* the smart choice.  I encourage the OP to look at JAMA, Apache Commons Math, or other good packages that are out there.

Comment: @paulsm4 :- Yes much better answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no "matrix class" built into the standard libraries.

Yes, there are many linear algebra libraries available.  For example:

- http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/
- http://commons.apache.org/math/

Comment: apache commons seems a better choice since it is more of a "standard"... I mean the commons library is used a lot already so, what do you think?

Comment: If you're already using other Apache Commons libraries in your code, then yes, Apache Commons Math might be ideal for you.  Otherwise, just "shop around" :)  Two additional links: [JBLAS](http://jblas.org/), and [Performance-of-java-matrix-math-libraries](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/529457/performance-of-java-matrix-math-libraries)

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/).

JAMA is a basic linear algebra package for Java. It provides user-level classes for constructing and manipulating real, dense matrices.  It is meant to provide sufficient functionality for routine problems, packaged in a way that is natural and understandable to non-experts.  It is intended to serve as the standard matrix class for Java...

Comment: Hmm but JAMA's last release in the change log is 2005 :(

Comment: Although I am not a JAMA user, not having recent activity can be a good thing.  If a project has not released in a while, you should look at the test coverage, open issues and docs.  The lack of activity could be a signal that the project is mature and will "just work".

Comment: It's actually a sign that the authors don't have interest in developing it any more.  they say so on the website.  However, in a shocking move, they fixed a long standing infinite loop bug very recently when they updated it for the first time in years!

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend [EJML](http://code.google.com/p/efficient-java-matrix-library/)
 The following functionality is provided:
•Basic Operators (addition, multiplication, ... )
•Matrix Manipulation (extract, insert, combine, ... )
•Linear Solvers (linear, least squares, incremental, ... )
•Decompositions (LU, QR, Cholesky, SVD, Eigenvalue, ...)
•Matrix Features (rank, symmetric, definitiveness, ... )
•Random Matrices (covariance, orthogonal, symmetric, ... )
•Different Internal Formats (row-major, block)
•Unit Testing