# Android: Libraries to work with Matrix

Tags: android, jama

I need to work with matrix in Android and I'm not sure about what library would be better. I have seen some examples using JAMA, but I read this other question on here:

[Performance of Java matrix math libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529457/performance-of-java-matrix-math-libraries)

And I could see JAMA is quite old fashion and slow, and 1 user recommend to use JBLAS, because it works fine with multicore machines.

The thing is I'm doing this application for a mobile phone, and I'm not sure if JBLAS performace difference with JAMA is going to be as big as in a computer. So I would like to know: ¿What matrix library would you recommend me to use in an Android application?