# JAMA Matrix performance

Tags: java, performance, matrix, profiler, jama

First of all, sorry for my bad English, but I need your help.

I have developed a simulation program with java swing where I have used lots of matrix calculations. My program is just finished but I need to speed up my performance. So I have used the java visual vm profiler to identify performance problems. I recognized that the initialization of Jama Matrices needs a lot of time. After running my program I had over 3 MB allocated Objects by JAMA. That's a lot of, isn't it? I think that's why the performance is bad.

Is there any better library than jama for matrices?  I am using 3x3 matrices and I need multiplication and inverse operations or is there anything else i can do?

Comment: @blueArrow Please see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529457/performance-of-java-matrix-math-libraries?rq=1)

Comment: @hexafraction what do you mean with your question? i use the JAMA library.

Comment: @AlexeyOdintsov i saw that question but it didn't helped me so far.

Answer (score 1):

Usually matrix math libraries are not optimized for speed on small matrices.
You can see for yourself by taking a few [*stackshots*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771), which are liable to show a large fraction of time in overhead functions like memory allocation and option checking.

What you can do instead (which I've done) is write special-purpose routines to do the multiplication and inverse, since you know the matrices are 3x3.
Multiplication is trivial and you can unroll the whole thing.

Inverse of a 3x3 matrix can also be done in less code than coffee :)
[*Wikipedia gives you the formula.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Inversion_of_3.C3.973_matrices)

Whatever you do, try to minimize memory allocation.