# Convenient and fast 3D vector math in Java

Tags: java, performance, math, game-physics

In general, I like programming in Java much more than C++ mostly because linking of libraries is much easier (no "dependency hell") and because there are great packages with a lot of functionality out of the box. I also like java tools like jMonkey and Processing.

However, I very often do something with physics where I need fast math with 3D vectors. And I didn't find any convenient way how to do it in Java both performance efficient and readable ( C++ constructs like macros, overloaded operators, structs, and passing variables by reference are very helpful tools for this purpose ).

For example **leapfrog integrator of a mass particle in central forcefield**. In C++ I can make something like this ( using overloaded operators for type float3 ):

```
float   ir2      =  1.0f/dot(vec_pos,vec_pos);
float   ir       =  sqrt(ir2);
float3  vec_G    = -vec_pos / (ir2*ir);
        vec_v   += vec_G*dt;
        vec_pos += vec_v*dt;
```

readable code in Java would look like:

```
float   ir2      =  1.0f/vec_pos.mag2();
float   ir       =  sqrt(ir2);
float3  vec_G    =  vec_pos.mult( -ir2*ir);
        vec_v    .addLocal( vec_G.multLocal( dt ) );
        vec_pos  .addLocal( vec_v.mult     ( dt ) );
```

which is not very good for performance since it **allocates new objects as temporary variabales** where "Local" method is not possible to use. I can optimize it by defining new methods for fused-multiply-add like:

```
float   ir2      =  1.0f/vec_pos.mag2();
float   ir       =  sqrt(ir2);
float3  vec_G    =  vec_pos.mult( -ir2*ir);
        vec_v    .addLocal_vec_times_scalar( vec_G, dt );
        vec_pos  .addLocal_vec_times_scalar( vec_v, dt );
```

But it is not very convenient to define specialized method for all possible combinations of arithmetic operations with float3 vector ... like:

```
  float3.addLocal_vec1_times_vec2_times_scalar()
```

An other strategy how to avoid allocation of temporary objects on-the-fly is to define this temporary variables once as some static global variables (which is not nice coding style) or as properties of enclosing class like:

```
class asteroide{
   // state variables
   float3 vec_pos;
   float3 vec_v; 
   // temporary variables
   float3 vec_G,vec_dpos;

   void update_leapfrog(float dt){
        float   ir2      =  1.0f/vec_pos.mag2();
        float   ir       =  sqrt(ir2);
        vec_G            .set_mult( vec_pos, -ir2*ir );
        vec_v            .addLocal( vec_G.multLocal( dt ) );
        dpos             .set_mult( vec_v, dt );
        vec_pos          .addLocal( dpos );
   }
}
```

In both cases there is **performance cost for dereferencing pointers** to this objects. It also make asteroide object **more memory consuming**.

There is also **performance penalty for calling object methods** (even if I try to make them "final" and "static" so JIT can inline them effectively ). According to my test using float3.mult() is 2-3x slower than just multiplication of 3 float.

So **I often end up writing complex vector algebra computations using just float** , to avoid this performance penalties. :((( But than it is not readable at all. Doing rigid body dynamics and aerodynamics computation in this way is pain in the ass. **It is as bad as Fortran77 programs 40 years ago !!!!** ( just for curiosity see eg. code of Xfoil http://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/xfoil/ )

What strategy you recommend for doing vector math in Java both performance efficient and convenient (~readable)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Performance of Java matrix math libraries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529457/performance-of-java-matrix-math-libraries)

Comment: @Alan, no this is not a question about performance, this is a question about syntax.  The OP wants to write mathematical expressions in Java that look like what he would write on paper.

Comment: @James, more accurately: this is a question about performance, but also one of syntax.  I will concede, however, that I may have placed too much emphasis on the former than the latter.

Comment: It's about the compromise: If I wan't to write nice readable vector math performance sucks.

Comment: @ProkopHapala, that's the rub: it seems to me that you can write matrix code that is a) fast, b) readable, and c) in Java... The problem is that you only get to pick two.  I usually either write it with floats or grab the best performing matrix library that I can use depending on how much vector math is needed.  Either way I resign myself to ugly matrix math code (in comparison to matlab/octave) and comment it thoroughly.  The other approach I have played with is to write sufficiently large matrix bits in C/C++ and call using JNI.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a real answer, but way too long for a comment.

How did you measure the performance? All optimizations need a while; if your measurement took less than a few seconds, then just forget it.

In theory, JIT should be capable of optimizing away the needless allocation.

Concerning ugliness: Sure, with names like `addLocal_vec_times_scalar` it must be ugly. Something like `addProduct` would do.

> There is also performance penalty for calling object methods (even if I try to make them "final" and "static" so JIT can inline them effectively )

This is not needed, as JIT can see if the method was overriden somewhere.

> What strategy you recommend for doing vector math in Java both performance efficient and convenient (~readable)?

Don't try to make it look like C. Define a few methods like fused multiply and ignore rare cases. If you're using names like `float3.addLocal_vec1_times_vec2_times_scalar`, it simply must be ugly. What's wrong with

```
 vec1.addProduct(vec2, vec3, someScalar)
```

Comment: It is not about ugly names, it's about generality (reusability) of the code. the methods are just to specialized. I don't like to write again and again almost the same code for each combination of arguments.

Comment: @ProkopHapala I understand, but there are not so many common argument combinations, you'll use maybe 5-10 of them all the time and ignore the inefficiencies with the others (if any; I can't think of more than 10 useful combinations). If your vectors were large, then you could use something smarter, but with float3 there's no room left.