# Where is the documentation for Matrix Toolkits Java and Netlib-Java?

Tags: java, matrix, mtj, netlib

I set out to install some fast matrix and BLAS libraries for Java, and settled on MTJ (backed by netlib-java) based on the results of [Java Matrix Benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8440974/3280780).  I believe I have everything installed via Maven, but I can't find any credible documentaiton for these libraries.

The logical starting point would be the github pages:

[MTJ](https://github.com/fommil/matrix-toolkits-java)

[netlib](https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java)

...But I can't find a link to any tutorials or javadoc beyond the incredibly terse MTJ wiki section on Github.  Netlib's source appears to be in fortran (with F2J as a compilation step) so I can't crawl directly though source in lieu of javadoc, either.

To make things even more baffling, there appears to be some sort of Javadoc for MTJ out there hosted by [a German university](http://www.inf.uni-konstanz.de/algo/lehre/ws05/pp/mtj/index.html) for some reason, that references packages (like nni.BLAS) that don't appear to be part of the MTJ library that Maven made for me.  There's another [even sketchier Javadoc](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/projectsfiles/f2j/javadoc/org/netlib/blas/Dgemv.html) hosted somewhere inside the University of Tennessee that, while having no apparent connection to the netlib-java project, does somehow have a Javadoc page that seems to explain the three extra integer arguments that netlib-java's DGEMV implementation uses (offsets of some sort?).  If I look at the fortran documentation [inside the netlib-java distribution](https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java/blob/master/netlib/BLAS/dgemv.f) for DGEMV, it has the eleven standard arguments that I would expect from DGEMV.

So here are my questions:

1.) Is there official documentation for MTJ/netlib?  If so, where?

2.) If there is no official documentation, are there any other resources out there that would allow someone to learn to use this library?  If this project isn't used exclusively by the developers, then people are learning to use it somehow.  How?

3.) If a Java version of netlib's 11-argument DGEMV isn't installed as part of MTJ via Maven, then what is this 14-argument thing on my hard drive?

Thanks.

Comment: in the current version there are numerous tests under src/test/java, so one  may see how the various methods are invoked; besides there are  javadoc comments which briefly explain what is being implemented (for example, the javadoc of BiCG solver reads "BiCG solver. BiCG solves the unsymmetric linear system <code>Ax = b</code> * using the Preconditioned BiConjugate Gradient method.")

Answer (score 1):

If you download MTJ via Maven, you can also download the Javadoc and source jars at that time. (IntelliJ IDEA will do this for you automagically.) The jar is called `mtj-1.0.2-javadoc.jar` and contains comprehensive Javadoc. Once upon a time, this seemed to be available on a website, but that site seems to be gone.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I've seen so far:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_Toolkit_Java

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/googlecode/matrix-toolkits-java/mtj/1.0.3/mtj-1.0.3-javadoc.jar) is link to jar archive with complete javadoc of latest stable MTJ. Just unzip it with tool such 7zip or similar. I agree that lack of guides related to this library might be dauting.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a site for mtj 1.0.3-snapshot on divshot.io:

http://mtj103.divshot.io/

Hope this helps.

Comment: The website seems to be down. Is there another address where it can be found? Is this actual documentation or javadoc?