# Changing the column size of 2D array at runtime

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

In the code below,I have defined a (2x2) 2D array, `arr`. And then I declare a one dimensional String array `a` with 5 elements, and assign it to the first row of the 2D array. Why am I allowed to do this, and why does not it throw array index out of bound exception?

I think it may be due to the reference assignment but still I am confuse about how one is allowed to change the array dimension at runtime.

```
String a[] = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };

String[][] arr= new String[2][2];

int x;

arr[0] = a;
x = arr[0].length;
System.out.print("The row length is "+ x);
```

Output:The row length is 5.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen After assignment the row length changes to 5.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know this, sort of.  `arr[0]` is a reference to a 1D array, and you may make any assignment you wish.  In Java, 2D (or 3D, etc.) array can be _jagged_, meaning that the second dimensions do not all have to be the same.

Comment: For reference, you don't have to define the 2nd dimension's length at all. `String[][] arr = new String[1][];` is already valid, whereas it throws an error if you either remove the the size for first dimension or just initialize the size of the second dimension

Comment: @XtremeBaumer so, it seems the second dimension does not matter..

Comment: What are you using this for ?

Comment: For performance consider other approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529457/performance-of-java-matrix-math-libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no multi-dimensional arrays in Java.

`String[][]` describes one dimensional array of one dimensional arrays. It is not necessary that each sub array must have the same length.

new String[2][2] is just syntactic sugar for

```
String[][] arr = new String[2][]
arr[0] = new String[2];
arr[1] = new String[2];
```

`arr[0] = a` reassigns the reference from two element String array to another 5-elemen one. The 2 element array is no longer referenced and occasionally GC'ed.

To copy elements from `a` to `arr` use:

```
System.arraycopy(a, 0, arr[0], 0, a.length);
```

Which will throw the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Java consider that `arr[0] = a;` as an array that's initialize with `a` .

this An asymmetric multidimensional array. look at this picture.

[image]

Another way to create an asymmetric array is to initialize just an array’s fi rst dimension,
and defi ne the size of each array component in a separate statement:

```
int [][] args = new int[4][];
args[0] = new int[5];
args[1] = new int[3];
```

This technique reveals what you really get with Java: arrays of arrays that, properly
managed, offer a multidimensional effect.

Answer (score 1):

What actually happens is nested arrays (same as in C/C++):

```
array[][] (actually just array[])
+---+ +---+ +---+ +---+ +---+
|   | |   | |   | |   | |   | .
| 0 | | 1 | | 2 | | 3 | | 4 | .
|   | |   | |   | |   | |   | .
+-+-+ +-+-+ +---+ +---+ +---+
  |     |
  v     v
arr[] arr[]
+---+ +---+
|   | |   |
| 0 | | 0 |
|   | |   |
+---+ +---+
|   | |   |
| 1 | | 1 |
|   | |   |
+---+ +---+
|   | |   |
| 2 | | 2 |
|   | |   |
+---+ +---+
 ...   ...
```

So first you access array[], and then another array (the nested one).
If you want **raw performance**, avoid doing this, use a special [math matrix lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529457/performance-of-java-matrix-math-libraries).
Also if you have a lot of empty cells in the matrix, consider using Maps instead.
And for the fancy ascii stuff I use [this](http://asciiflow.com/).